# How to resoslve this error?

Tags: reactjs

this code is giving an error:

> TyperError: cannot read property of undefined how to solve this!!!

```
import React from 'react';

    class App extends React.Component {
        render(){
            return (
                <div>
                  <h1>{this.props.propArray}</h1>
                  <h1>{this.props.propString}</h1>
                  <h1>{this.props.propNumber}</h1>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }

    App.propTypes = {
        propArray : React.PropTypes.array,
        propString: React.PropTypes.string,
        propNumber: React.PropTypes.number
    }

    App.defaultProps = {
        propArray :[1,2,3,4,5],
        propString: "uthej",
        propNumber: 69.
    }
    export default App;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1Kc0.png)

Answer (score 0):

From [`react-docs`](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) :

> **React.PropTypes has moved into a different package since React v15.5. Please use the prop-types library instead.**

You need to import `prop-types` package to remove this error.

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

App.propTypes = {
        propArray : PropTypes.array,
        propString: PropTypes.string
}
```